# knockoutjs subscribe method is invoked 2 times

Tags: knockout.js

In knockoutjs subscribe method, I also set the value of property inside subscribe method, that why the method is invoked 2 times, first one when the value is change in UI and second time when value is changed inside subscribe method.

Anyone know how to avoid this case.

This is my sample code:

```
var ViewModel = function(first) {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    self.firstName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        alert(newValue);
        self.firstName(newValue.toUpperCase());       
    });

};
```

Also put to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ndkhoiits/4ABuq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you would probably need a computed observable with a getter and setter

```
var ViewModel = function(first) {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    self.firstNameForView = ko.computed({        
        read: function () {            
            return self.firstName();
        },        
        write: function (value) {            
            self.firstName(value.toUpperCase());
        },        
        owner: this    
    });
};
```

Now use the firstNameForView in your data binding.